# How get Area of Objects inside a Block/autocad into a variable using lisp

Tags: autocad, autolisp

Here is the Code;

```
                                       (setq Tobjs (vla-Explode Tvlaobj))


                                        (setq ObjectsAsList (vlax-safearray->list (vlax-variant-value Tobjs ) ) )

                                                                    (foreach % ObjectsAsList

                                                                      (setq TSublayerNew (vla-get-layer %))

                                                                      (cond ((eq TSublayerNew TLaynemeShort)


                                                                        (command "_.AREA" "_O" %)

                                                                         (setq Teee (getvar 'area))
                                                                         (setq Ttvm (+ Ttvm Teee))
                                                                         (princ (strcat (rtos Teee 2 0) " | "))


                                                                         (setq Tcntr (+ Tcntr 1))

                                                                        )
                                                                      )

                                                                    )


                                                                  (setq TNumF Ttvm)
                                                                  (princ (strcat (rtos TNumF 2 2)))
```

I want to get the Total area for all Region and Solids in Block (Tobjs) into variable TNumF, if it matches the condition,

it give an error: bad argument value: AutoCAD command: #

please help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because % is entity as vla-object, but command needs entity, so try this code:

```
(command "_.AREA" "_O" (vlax-vla-object->ename % ))
```

Comment: Its Really Amazing Wow. Thanks